# Always left join in OneToOne mapping with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

I have two entity `Person` and `BlacklistInfo` and they have `OneToOne` relation between them.

Person.java

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "person_tbl")
public class Person {
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    @Id
    private Long personId;
    
    // ... other members

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "person_id")
    private BlacklistInfo blacklistInfo;
}
```

AdditionalInfo.java

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "blacklist_info_tbl")
public class BlacklistInfo {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    private Long personId;
   
    // ... other members
}
```

`BlacklistInfo` for a `Person` can be null. Currently **I want to find the non-blacklisted people**.

I can do the operation by doing one of the followings:

1. Query all the persons and remove blacklisted from them
2. Do a left join query and check the `personId` of `BlacklistInfo` is null

   ```sql
   select p from Person p left join p.blacklistInfo where p.blacklistInfo.personId is null
   ```

Question is: `Can I do the 2nd operation without explicitly mentioning left join the in query section? Can it be done by modifying entity relationship ?`

I am using `hibernate-5.4.12.Final` with `spring-boot-2.2.x`

Comment: It _can_ be done, but it's simplest as you have it. (JPQL really _ought_ to intelligently support `WHERE p.blacklistInfo IS NULL`, but I don't think it does.)

Answer (score 0):

How else would you want to query this information? It's totally fine to use JPQL/HQL for doing this.